# Feature Extraction for multiple text columns for classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

which is the correct way to extract features from multiple text columns and apply any classification algorithm on it?
please suggest me, if i am going wrong

**example dataset**

[image]

**Independent Variables :** Description1,Description2, State, NumericCol1,NumericCol2

**Dependent Variable :** TargetCategory

**Code:**

```
########### Feature Exttraction for Text Data #####################
######### Description1 (it can be any wordembedding technique like countvectorizer, tfidf, word2vec,bert..etc)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 500, 
                              ngram_range = (1,3),
                              stop_words = "english")
X_Description1 = tfidf.fit_transform(df["Description1"].tolist())

######### Description2 (it can be any wordembedding technique like countvectorizer, tfidf, word2vec,bert..etc)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 500, 
                              ngram_range = (1,3),
                              stop_words = "english")
X_Description2 = tfidf.fit_transform(df["Description2"].tolist())


######### State (have 100 unique entries thats why used BinaryEncoder)
import category_encoders as ce
binary_encoder= ce.BinaryEncoder(cols=['state'],return_df=True)
X_state = binary_encoder.fit_transform(df["state"])


import scipy
X = scipy.sparse.hstack((X_Description1, 
                         X_Description2,
                         X_state,
                         df[["NumericCol1", "NumericCol2"]].to_numpy())).tocsr()

y = df['TargetCategory']


##### train Test Split ########
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=111)

##### Create Model Model ######
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, classification_report, cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn import metrics 

# Baseline Random forest based Model
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'gini', n_estimators=1000, verbose=1, n_jobs = -1, 
                             class_weight = 'balanced', max_features = 'auto')
rfcg = rfc.fit(X_train,y_train) # fit on training data


####### Prediction ##########
predictions = rfcg.predict(X_test)
print('Baseline: Accuracy: ', round(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)*100, 2))
print('\n Classification Report:\n', classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to use multiple columns as input in scikit-learn is by using the [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer).

[Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data) is an example on how to use it with heterogeneous data.